# Can I Passively redirecting air currents with forest gardening?

Tags: environment, weather, ecology, forestry

A group of evil farmers have developed a technique for manipulation of the weather on a large scale whereby the land is altered to effect the temperature of the air above and to act as a trap for important insects, pollen, seeds, pesticides, and sprayed fertilizer agents.

The structure they have designed consists of the following:

A cool swamp followed by border of of thick leafy bushes and trees, and then a warm reflective zone to create a warm counter current.
This will repel particulates and substances.

There is a line of toxic trees that taint the air with shortlived, heavy, and toxic chemicals.
They are embedded in a swampy strip inside the reflective zone and insulated by thick growth to provide an area that blocks insect movement.

They use special copper coloured reflective trees for warm zone.

The swamp is where particulates end up trapped if they aren't blown back.

Each section as described is mandatory due to the crazed fascist beliefs held by the farmers.

The farmers are primarily creating these structures for preexisting farms or land near preexisting farms.

What can they do to create the artificial swamp and forest sections as cheaply as possible in the long run while remaining effective?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: There's quite a bit of preamble that doesn't seem to relate to the question - which seems to be how to build a swamp that lasts and is cheap? Is that right? That's a fine question and you've definitely given us worldbuilding context that we like to have, but just to be clear.... that is the question right?

Comment: It isn't specifically about the swamp, but about the whole structure which consists of artificial forest and swamp areas. I shall edit to make that more clear.

Comment: There are urban planners that worry about the temperature and climate of cities being different than the surrounding areas. It also connects to a variety of health effects related to air and water quality. Usually as a remedy they suggest planting more trees and having more green spaces. So if you want a science based answer that might be a place to start.

Comment: A picture is worth a thousand words - a simple diagram would make this question much easier to understand.

Answer (score 1):

**They site their structure in an existing large swamp.**

That is the cheapest way.  Find it and use it.  There exist large swampy areas and usually they are not very populated.

As regards the forest section, they can build up part of the swamp to make it drier and this area will naturally turn into forest.

Comment: Because they are evil farmers with already established farms not all of them have easy access to preexisting swamps.

Comment: @ProfessorMoreRight - I assumed that this structure would not be built atop existing evil farms.  Because then how are you going to grow evil crops?  Or could an evil rice paddy be used for the swamp?  Double evil duty, you know?

Comment: They do use plants that pull double duty. Some of the reflective trees used are actually cherry trees though the fruits despite being especially flavorful are more pit than most commercial cherries.

Comment: Taking an extra delicious cherry and making its stone extra large really is dislikably evil.